# How to find if video is syndicated on YouTube data api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a website with the ability for users to embed YouTube videos. Before letting the user do it our CMS checks if the video is embeddable and/or country restricted and sends a warning.

The check is done with a call to:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=[video_id]&key=[google_key]&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

Now we are developing an app and we found out that not all embeddable videos are allowed, but there seems to be another option called syndicate to have the permission to show a video outside of a webpage.

How can I check if the video has the syndicated flag when I know the id?

There is a flag you can add during a youtube search to only show embeddable or syndicated video on the  [Youtube v3 data api search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) `videoEmbeddable` and `videoSyndicated`.

[Videos overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) has a `embeddable` flag that I was using for the website I can't find any reference to the syndicate flag. I also can't find any other references other than a syndicate flag with an "allowed" value that seemed to exist in v2 but there are no references in v3 anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two concepts embeddable and syndicated.
iOS devices use an iFrame so they basically embed. 
Android devices that use player API can check syndicated.

When you do a [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), you can set [videoEmbeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoEmbeddable) and [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated) to true.

Or if you are iterating through videos, for each video, you can do a [video->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with video id and check [status.embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) in the response.

Here is a [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html) about this topic, even though examples are in v2, information is still relevant.

**UPDATE**

As per the comment by Kesty If you need to check the syndicate flag. You need to make request to `/v3/search?q=[video_id]` along with the flag and then another call to check the video details. It works because you can do a search with video id as q,

Comment: The problem is that the status.embeddable is only relevant to the videoEmbeddable and I would also need to check if is syndicated but it doesn't seem I can with v3 only v2 has a syndicate flag

Comment: In this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) You can find `videoSyndicated` tag related information to distinguish which video is syndicated.

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't check videoSyndicated with `/v3/videos?id=[video_id]` you have to do use `/v3/search?q=[video_id]` with the flag and then another call to check the video details. It works because you can do a search with video id as q, and that is what I was missing. If you could add this info on your answer I'll check correct and award the bounty.

Comment: Sure Let me add this,

Answer (score 2):

v3 also has a syndicate flag so declaring type key to video and searching in the filter type as shown in docs in filter for parameters should archive what you are looking for as shown in these google docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 0):

Using the [v3 API for YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), the following query will get you the syndication status via search/list:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=stuff&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

One requirement is that the use of the `videoSyndication` parameter requires that you set the `type` parameter to `video`.

The results will contain videos that match your `videoSyndication` setting (**any** or **true**).